# Cannot assert Bad Request [HTTP 400 error] using RestSharp. Throws System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, restsharp, web-api-testing

Using RestSharp I have written the following test and the expected outcome is to return error 400 with some error messages in Json format.

But the following test fails at await client.PostAsync(request) and throws *"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Request failed with status code BadRequest"* and does not reach the Assertion statement.

Using Fiddler I verified my request and Reponses are working as expected.

Would appreciate any advice to solve this. Thank you!

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Test1Async()
    {
        var jsonData = json;
        var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddStringBody(jsonData, ContentType.Json);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
        Assert.AreEqual(400, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

Solution that worked. Thanks Nicolas VERHELST...

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Test1Async()
    {
        var jsonData = json;
        var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddStringBody(jsonData, ContentType.Json);
        var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are worried about the method `PostAsync(..)` throwing when you get a bad status (e.g. 400), you can use `ExecutePostAsync(..)` instead.

See the table in here: https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your response. Yes the objective of this test to send an invalid geo location format, and the API will return error 400 with a JSON validation error as follows.

{
  "messages": [
    "Invalid latitude : -91",
    "Invalid longitude : 181",
    "Invalid latitude : 91",
    "Invalid longitude : -181"
  ]
}

so my test is about asserting whether it returns 400. But the test is not reaching the assertion statement.

Comment: Ohhh, so just add a try catch? Or use `ExecutePostAsync`? Look at the table here: https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html (you can see that some methods throw on bad status, some don't)